# MQ137 Ammonia sensor - Pins not labeled

Tags: sensor

I recently purchased an MQ137 Ammonia sensor and breakout board. Unfortunately the item came with the two parts separated with no markings as to the orientation. Can anyone advise on the pin layout?

There item is from [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/261183438507?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1439.l2649) I believe this is the [datasheet](https://iprototype.nl/docs/methane-CNG-gas-sensor-MQ-4-technisch-datasheet.pdf)[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to figure 2 in the referenced datasheet, it doesn't matter how you fit the sensor in the socket. It fits in only two positions in the socket, 180 degrees rotated. Pins A and B are interchangeable according to the circuit on the right and are both double according to the top-middle drawing where the heater pins (H) are the middle ones of the triplets.

[image]